# How to obtain underlaying elements of each item in foreach loop using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, list, foreach, iterator

I'm not sure how to exactly ask this question but this is the problem:

I got a list which I filter by SubTypeId(Key = 1 or Key = 2), that looks like this:

[image]

As u can see "Key = 1" has 4 objects within: 0, 1, 2 and 3. All these objects have the same TypeDescription. How can i achieve this element "TypeDescription" once within this for each loop?

Thanks in advance!:)

Comment: Well. `item` is a collection. You need to index the collection. Your first object is index 0, next is 1, etc, etc.

Comment: the result of a `GroupBy` is enumerable itself (containing all items in the group). So you can loop over them. `foreach (var subitem in item) { ... }`.

Comment: use `.ToArray()` to convert it to an indexed collection

Comment: item.FirstOrDefault().TypeDescription

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options here:

1. Group your elements array by two parameters:

```cs
var res = Reports.GroupBy(u => new {u.SubTypeId, u.TypeDescription})
                     .Select(r => new
                      {
                         r.Key, // Key here consists of two elements
                         items = r.Select(i => new
                         {
                             i.DocumentPath,
                             i.Id,
                             i.Name,
                             i.SubTypeDescription,
                             i.TypeId
                         })
                      }).ToList();
```

In this case, as a result, you will have a collection of `SubtypeId` and `TypeDescription` items grouped, containing a collection of all other elements you need.

2. Create a nested grouping:

```cs
var res2 = Reports.GroupBy(u => u.SubTypeId)
                          .Select(r => r.ToList()
                                        .GroupBy(r => r.TypeDescription)
                                        .Select(item=> new {
                                             item.Key,
                                             items = item.Select(i => new 
                                             {
                                                  i.DocumentPath,
                                                  i.Id,
                                                  i.Name,
                                                  i.SubTypeDescription,
                                                  i.TypeId
                                             })
                                         })).ToList();
```

In this case, you will have a bit more nestings, but the data output will probably be more close to what you were initially requesting.

---

A few advises:

1. Please try to avoid array manipulations inside the loop subject, like in the above case, you did array grouping in the `foreach` collections input section. Instead, assign the array manipulations to a separate variable before the loop.
2. Instead of anonymous objects, try using real `class` models.
   *Note: in above examples, I've used Anonymous object just for demonstration purposes.*